# Is it possible to get instances of all Singletons when I know their System.Assembly.Type?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I get all classes that inherit from my abstract base class like this:

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var classesThatInheritFromBase = myAssembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType ==  
typeof(BaseClass));
```

Now can I somehow get all/any instances of all these classes? Does this still belong to reflection?

Answer (score 0):

It would be the easiest if you made all your singletons implement an interface, say `ISingleton`, with a single method returning the instance, let's call it `GetInstance`. Then you could get all the types that have `ISingleton` in their `GetInterfaces()` enumerable, catch the `GetInstance` method by reflection and invoke it.

There is no way to simply find all instances of a given type, as you would have to somehow walk through the entire allocated heap space and stack space of all running threads, which is... hard to achieve to say the least.